# this.props.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to React and having trouble setting parent state from child.

Parent Component: Router.js

```
class Router extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            login: true,
        }
    }
    handler() {
        console.log("hi");
        this.setState({
            login: true,
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                <Route exact path="/" component={ Register }></Route>
...other routes
                    <Route path="/login" handler={this.handler} component={ Login } />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Router;
```

Child Component Login.js

```
class Login extends Component {
...some code to get back end node js data
if(got node data){
      this.props.handler();
     this.props.history.push('/home');
}
 render (){
        return (
<div>
<button className="button" onClick = {this.checkUser.bind(this)}>
                            Login
                        </button>
<div>
)
}
```

I keep getting "this.props.handler is not a function"

Did i format my handler wrong? I am a bit confused.

Thank

Comment: Did you console out this.props in Login component? Does it have handle method?

Comment: @sunny No it only has history, location and match. Im wondering why it doesnt have handle method

Comment: I see, fixed it! Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to pass handler prop to Login component not the Route component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `this.handler` to the `Route` component not to `Login`, when you do

```js
<Route path="/login" handler={this.handler} component={ Login } />
```

You have two choices to pass `this.handler` to `Login` component.

You can either pass props via [render](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)

```js
<Route path="/login" render={ () => <Login handler={this.handler} />} />
```

or nest it

```js
<Route path="/login">
  <Login handler={this.handler} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome @James. Could you mark it as the answer when it works to let others know it worked?